# on click not working as expected on dynamically created elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tag when clicked alerts the data-value of the tag. It works fine , but doesn't works when i click on dynamically created elements.

```
<img id="no_p_fav" src="http://localhost:8000/icons/non_star.png">
```

Below is how i create dynamic elements

```
 $('.all_candidate_bar').prepend('<div id = "icons"> <a class = "favorite" data-value = "'+data.msg.id+'" > <img id = "no_p_fav" src="{{url("/icons/non_star.png")}}" ></img></a></div>');
```

Below function doesn't work on dynamically created elements but works fine on elements which were there when the page was loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.favorite').on('click',function(){
        var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
        alert(candidate_id);
    }); 
});
```

I have also tried this

```
 $('#icons').on('click','a.favorite',function(){//myFunction});
 $('a').on('click','.favorite',function(){//myFunction});
```

How do i make it work for elements for both dynamic and static elements ?

Comment: `'a .favorite'` => `'a.favorite'`. Former will select elements having class `favorite` inside anchor.

Comment: that was a typo , yes in this case. when i click on it only one element works. rest are not working.

Comment: Google event delegation, you need to delegate the event handling to closest static parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `#icon` is also created dynamically you cannot use event delegation against it, you need a higher level element that is there since the beginning, `body` for instance:

```
$('body').on('click','.favorite',function(){//myFunction});
```

The `a` also won't work, since the event is not delegated in this case, it is accessing the element itself

```
$('a').on('click','.favorite',function(){//myFunction}); // won't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.favorite',function(){
        var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
        alert(candidate_id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created element you need to to delegate the event
$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('body').on('click','.favorite',function(){
        var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
        alert(candidate_id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function  like this way

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.favorite',function(){
      var candidate_id = $(this).data('value');
      alert(candidate_id);
});
```